# Can Google Calendar API return empty calendar spaces?

Tags: json, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

**Before I begin, this is not a specific coding question, so I apologise for that first. It's more of a conceptual question.**

Can the Google Calendar API return data for all calendar slots including timeslots that have no bookings/appointments at all? I am working with LibCal (springshare.com/libcal/) and their API is extremely limited but the system does synch bookings to Google Calendar. We use LibCal to facilitate bookings at the organisation I work for.

Problem is that what I can see returned is just current booked slots. We are using the calendar for room bookings and 'the powers that be' want to return a graphic table of all available timeslots with colour coding to mark the currently booked and unbooked rooms. Additionally, in each table cell, they want to have the name of the person (and group name) who has booked the room. Can it be done?

It's my first foray into the Calendar API so I am still trying to figure out what is possible and if it can do what I need it to do.

Comment: To my knowledge the API only returns rows where there is data.

Comment: Yeah i thought it was like that unfortunately. Think I will solve my problem by prepoulating empty data slots and have the JSON feed overlay the empty slots and fill in the booked ones. Best way to deal with it that I can think of.